# Force subprocess to use Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, shell, subprocess

So, I was trying to write a Python script that utilized `subprocess` to call another Python script in the same directory. This was all going well until an import statement within the second script was reached of a Python 3-only library, and since the script was opened using `subprocess`, which in turn uses Python 2, an `ImportError` occurred.

How can I force `subprocess`, specifically `Popen()`, to use Python 3 to open the script? There does not seem to be advice on this online.

### Edit

While I always default to posting MWEs, for this question I believed it was unnecessary, but at any rate s soon as I proceeded to post it, it occurred to me to use 'python3' instead of just 'python',

```
stream = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'app.py'])
```

and now the app works. What is strange is that I have only one version of Python installed by myself (3.7), and `python` redirects to `python3`, so it is strange I had to manually specify `python3`.

Comment: What does your `subprocess` command currently look like? Would you not just pass the path of your `python3` as the first element in the command?

Comment: how about some code [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your issue?

Comment: `subprocess.run(['python3', scriptname])` should execute Python 3 on most platforms, including MacOS with Python 3 installed via Homebrew. If yours is different, perhaps investigate how it differs and how to solve this under your specific circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to force a script to be run with Python3:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import sys, subprocess

if sys.version_info[:2] < (3, 0):
    # FORCE PYTHON3
    code = subprocess.check_call(['python3'] + sys.argv)
    raise SystemExit(code)

print("Using Python v%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2])
```

Example when run in Bash:

```
> python3 force_python3.py                                                                                                                         
Using Python v3.7

> python2 force_python3.py                                                                                                                         
Using Python v3.7
```

Comment: Probably better to use `subprocess.check_call` or `subprocess.run` in most scenarios.

Comment: @tripleee: Just curious : why? If there's a good reason, I'd be happy to change the code.

Comment: Perhaps less important for this particular use case, though I'm not sure if your interpretation of the OP's question is the one I'd expect. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188 for a (perhaps too long) exposition of the differences.

Comment: @tripleee: `subprocess.run` doesn't seem to be available in Python 2.7.

Comment: Nope; again, see the link I provided above.

Comment: @tripleee: `check_call` it is, then!

Comment: Even though I answered my own question after the downvotes harangued me enough to write an MWE and expose a quirk of `subprocess`, thanks for your answer. I was not aware you could force a python version through code like that, and I will definitely remember this for the future!

Comment: @Coolio2654: Note that it's merely a workaround. You should investigate why the wrong Python version is called in the first place.

Comment: You could force the second script to use the same interpreter as the first by using `sys.executable` instead of hardcoding `'python3'`.

Comment: No, the goal is to explicitly force python3. If you want to use the same interpreter as the first one, using `import` should be enough.

Comment: You said you only had one version installed, so that's a moot point. Also importing a script isn't quite the same thing as executing it in a subprocess.